# Rotate ImageView Clockwise and Anti-Clockwise

Tags: android

I have created an `imageView` and would like to rotate it `clockwise` and `anti-clockwise` depending on which `button` is pressed. Whenever I press either the `clockwise or anti-clockwise button` the `imageView` does not rotate. The rotation only occurs if I press a `button` that is not `clockwise` or `anti-clockwise`. How would you solve this and make the rotation happen instantly?

#### activity_negative.xml

```
 <ImageView
  android:layout_width="170dp"
  android:layout_height="120dp"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:id="@+id/imgCircle"
  android:src="@drawable/ic_circle"
  android:clickable="false"/>
```

#### activity_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">

<solid
    android:color="#666666"/>

<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp" />

</shape>
```

#### image_rotate_clockwise

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:duration="1000"
 android:repeatCount="infinite"
 android:fromDegrees="0"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
 android:pivotX="50%"
 android:pivotY="50%"
 android:toDegrees="360" />
```

#### image_rotate_anticlockwise

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:fromDegrees="360"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="0" />
```

#### NegativeActivity.java

```
if ( v == CLOCKWISE ) {
        if (random == 1) {
            new CountDownTimer(100,1) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    CLOCKWISE.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    CLOCKWISE.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    Animation clockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NegativeActivity.this,R.anim.button_rotate_clockwise);
                    clockwise.setDuration(5000);
                    CIRCLE.startAnimation(clockwise);
                    Random r = new Random();
                    random = r.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1;
                    if(random == 1) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if(random == 2) {
                        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Blue");
                    }
                    else if(random == 3) {
                        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Red");
                    }
                    else if(random == 4) {
                        textQueston.setText("Spin the Circle Anti-Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if(random == 5) {
                        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Smaller");
                    }
                    else if(random == 6) {
                        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Larger");
                    }
                    else if (random == 7) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Faster Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if (random == 8) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Slower Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if (random == 9) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Faster Anti-Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if (random == 10) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Slower Anti-Clockwise");
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
    else if (v == ANTICLOCKWISE) {
        if (random == 4) {
            new CountDownTimer(100,1) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    ANTICLOCKWISE.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    ANTICLOCKWISE.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    Animation anti = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NegativeActivity.this,R.anim.button_rotate_anticlockwise);
                    anti.setDuration(5000);
                    CIRCLE.startAnimation(anti);
                    Random r = new Random();
                    random = r.nextInt(11 - 1) + 1;
                    if(random == 1) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if(random == 2) {
                        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Blue");
                    }
                    else if(random == 3) {
                        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Red");
                    }
                    else if(random == 4) {
                        textQueston.setText("Spin the Circle Anti-Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if(random == 5) {
                        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Smaller");
                    }
                    else if(random == 6) {
                        textQueston.setText("Make the Circle Larger");
                    }
                    else if (random == 7) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Faster Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if (random == 8) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Slower Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if (random == 9) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Faster Anti-Clockwise");
                    }
                    else if (random == 10) {
                        textQueston.setText("Rotate the Circle Slower Anti-Clockwise");
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: for rotation file try https://stackoverflow.com/a/44404220/8089770

Comment: @VishvaDave I have the rotation code from the link but it does not rotate the circle on click. I need the circle to rotate instantly.

Comment: Just add animation lines (3 lines) in onclick of the button.

Comment: @VishvaDave please see above where added the (3 lines) in the onClick of the button. But still not rotating instantly.

Comment: try to play with the duration timings. Check if it works or not make it less and more and test it.

Comment: @VishvaDave its working the problem was the reference I was using for the imageView. Changed the reference and working perfectly. Thanks for your help. :)